# How to overwrite a nested list using conditional list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I'm trying to check a nested for the bigger number in each and overwrite each nested list with just the value of the number with the biggest value.
I have done this using nested loops but I was wondering how to do this using conditional list comprehension.
Here's my nested loop solution:

```
list1 = [[1,2,4,3], [1,2,755,244], [1,2,6,1000] , [5,3,7,13]]
iterator = 0
for val1 in list1:
  for num in val1:
    if num == max(val1):
      list1[iterator] = num
  iterator +=1
```

Here's what I tried with list comprehension but the syntax is wrong:

```
num  for x in list1 for num in x if num ==max(x)
```

The error is: invalid syntax

Comment: What do you mean the syntax is wrong? Give the error. For one thing you seem to be missing the brackets.

Comment: The list comprehension part is giving me a syntax error. I'm only getting invalid syntax and it's pointing to the first for loop, I added a screenshot to my post

Comment: We don't want screenshots, post a [mcve] *as text*.

Comment: Generator expressions such as listcomp need to be in brackets. If you are doing listcomp then the expession needs to be inside a `[]`.

Comment: @jornsharpe2 in that case it's invalid syntax error pointing to the first for.

Comment: And what can we tell you without context? Hence the request for a MRE, **as text**.

Comment: Just a tip @random-xyz, your code is O(N^2) because of this line: `if num == max(val1):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coded you pasted works just fine. That being said you can write it much cleaner:

```
list1 = [[1,2,4,3], [1,2,755,244], [1,2,6,1000] , [5,3,7,13]]
iterator = 0
for index, val in enumerate(list1):
    list1[index] = max(val)
print(list1) # [4, 755, 1000, 13]
```

The cleaner yet, listcomp version with `max`:

```
list1 = [[1,2,4,3], [1,2,755,244], [1,2,6,1000] , [5,3,7,13]]
list1 = [max(lst) for lst in list1]
print(list1) # [4, 755, 1000, 13]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. that will return the biggest number. What I want to do actually is overwrite each of the nested lists with the max number in each without creating a new list. The same result I got with the nested loops.

Comment: Just do `list1 = [max(lst) for lst in list1]` (See my update)... Or is there a reason you don't want to put it in memory at all? If thats the case you can't use listcomp.